# Using Checksum to finddistinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #dbNames (reference int identity not null, name1 varchar(30), 
                       name2 varchar(30), dateadded datetime, primary key (reference))
insert into #dbNames ('Bert', 'Claire', '2010-01-01')
insert into #dbNames ('Claire', 'Bert', '2015-01-01')
```

I want the output of the query to be:

```
Claire Bert 2015-01-01
```

2015-01-01 is more recent than 2010-01-01.  Claire and Bert only have to be displayed on row once i.e. the most recent row.

I was thinking about creating Checksum column.  However, Checksum produces two distinct values:

```
declare @checksum int
declare @checksum2 int

set @Checksum = checksum('Claire,Bert')
set @Checksum2 = checksum('Bert,Claire')

print @checksum
print @checksum2
```

Is there an algorithm I can use so the values are the same i.e. in the above, @Checksum and @Checksum2 produce different results.

Comment: CHECKSUM computes a hash value, called the checksum, over its list of arguments. The hash value is intended for use in building hash indexes. If the arguments to CHECKSUM are columns, and an index is built over the computed CHECKSUM value, the result is a hash index. This can be used for equality searches over the columns.

Comment: Are you returning "Claire Bert" simply based on the date being most recent?  Or are you wanting SQL to know the name is potentially transposed, and to treat them as the same person and then evaluate the date?  I'm confused at your question.

Comment: Do you only need a query that returns one row?    Or one row for every pair of names?

Comment: You could try thinking about a solution that employs a split function and compares the contents of the derived tables produced by fn_Split('Claire,Bert') and fn_Split('Bert,Claire')

Comment: @ Tab Alleman, there are millions of row sin the table.  There should only be one row for each combination i.e. one row would cater for: Claire,Bert and Bert,Claire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into #dbNames
            (
                name1
            ,   name2
            ,   dateadded
            )
    VALUES  ('Bert', 'Claire', '2010-01-01')
        ,   ('Claire', 'Bert', '2015-01-01')
        ,   ('John', 'Smith', '2015-01-02')
        ,   ('Smith', 'John', '2015-02-01')
        ,   ('Joe', 'Blow', '2015-03-01')

;WITH
    cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT      *,
                    full_name = name1 + ' ' + name2,
                    alt_name  = name2 + ' ' + name1
        FROM        #dbNames
    ),
    cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT      c1.*,
                    final_name =
                        CASE 
                            WHEN c2.reference IS NULL THEN c1.full_name
                            WHEN c1.dateadded >= c2.dateadded THEN c1.full_name
                            ELSE c2.full_name
                        END
        FROM        cte1    c1
        LEFT JOIN   cte1    c2  ON (c1.full_name = c2.full_name OR c1.full_name = c2.alt_name)
                                AND c1.reference <> c2.reference
    ),
    cte3 AS
    (
        SELECT      *,
                    rownumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY final_name ORDER BY dateadded)
        FROM        cte2
    )

SELECT *
FROM cte3
WHERE rownumber = 1
```

I haven't tested it on millions of rows though.